# How to configure the lanuch.json file of vscode to automatically update the module when running debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, odoo, odoo-10

I am writing odoo module with vscode, I want to run the module with VScode debug mode, but I don't want to manually update the module, I want to write the configuration in lanuch.json, but I have found a lot of ways to find the write.

I tried a lot to write -u (module name) -d (database) into the args configuration, but it is invalid

```
"version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Odoo10",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",

        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/odoo-bin",
        "args": [
            "--config=${workspaceFolder}/odoo.conf",
            // "${workspaceFolder}/odoo.conf -u aatudo -d Odoo",
            // "${workspaceFolder}\C:\Odoo_env\odoo\odoo.conf -u aatudo -d 
                  Odoo",

        ],
        "debugOptions": [ 
            "RedirectOutput"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Odoo itself has a development mode which can come in handy when you are developing modules, development mode in odoo ensures two things:

- Along with `watchdog` module of python, odoo server is reloaded whenever change in python code detected in the directories listed in `addons_path`
- Instead of reading view files from database, view definitions are read directly from `xml` file, so change in xml view definitions and a page reload will reflect those changes in odoo. No need to update any module from commandline or odoo apps.

To use development mode, just append `--dev=all` to your odoo running command and don't forget to run `pip install watchdog` in your environment to install watchdog package for auto server reloading in case of change in Python code.